# mx:Canvas 's Show event equalivent in s:Group

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

As of Flex 4, I'm using `s:Group` instead of `mx:Canvas`.

With `s:Group` , show event is not fired when the container is visible like with `mx:Canvas`.  `creationComplete` event fire only once. How can I detect show event or something alike in Flex 4 or should I just use the `mx:Canvas` instead ?

Any kind help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what about `enterState` or `show` events?